# Change img src when on hover of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html

```
<div class="custom text-center threeBox ofsted">
  <a class="ofsted" title="ofsted report" href="http://reports.ofsted.gov.uk/">
    <img class="text-center ofstedLogo" src="images/ofsted_good_transparent.png" alt="ofsted good rating">
    <h3>Ofsted</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have written the following jquery which swaps the background colours on hover of a:

```
    $(".threeBox a").hover(
        function(){ // Mouse Over
            $(this).parent().addClass("swapBg");
        },
        function(){ // Mouse Out
            $(this).parent().removeClass("swapBg");
        }
    );
```

Which works great, but I need to swap the img.ofstedLogo src on hover to 'OFSTED_good_logo.jpg'. I've tried several changes to the jQuery code but can't get it to work. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** to get the `img` and **[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)** for changing the image source

```js
$(".threeBox a").hover(
        function(){ // Mouse Over
            $(this).parent().addClass("swapBg").find('img').attr('src','OFSTED_good_logo.jpg');
        },
        function(){ // Mouse Out
            $(this).parent().removeClass("swapBg").find('img').attr('src','images/ofsted_good_transparent.png');
        }
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom text-center threeBox ofsted">
  <a class="ofsted" title="ofsted report" href="http://reports.ofsted.gov.uk/">
    <img class="text-center ofstedLogo" src="images/ofsted_good_transparent.png" alt="ofsted good rating">
    <h3>Ofsted</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$(".threeBox a").hover(
        function(){ // Mouse Over
            $(this).parent().addClass("swapBg");
            $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/OFSTED_good_logo.jpg');
        },
        function(){ // Mouse Out
            $(this).parent().removeClass("swapBg");
            $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'images/ofsted_good_transparent.png');
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

This would do the job:

```
$(this).children('.ofstedLogo').attr('src', 'yourimagehere.png');
```

See [**attr**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to select the image and [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to change the src attribute:

```
$(".threeBox a").hover(
    function(){ // Mouse Over
        $(this).parent().addClass("swapBg");
        $(this).find('img.ofstedLogo').attr("src", "images/OFSTED_good_logo.jpg");
    },
    function(){ // Mouse Out
        $(this).parent().removeClass("swapBg");
        $(this).find('img.ofstedLogo').attr("src","images/ofsted_good_transparent.png");
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this effect with a graphic .. check out the jsfiddle example here:

jQuery direct image replacement

```
$(".twoBox > a").hover(
    function(){ // Mouse Over
        $(this).find('img:first').attr("src", 'http://blog.modernica.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/2-300x300.png');
    },
    function(){ // Mouse Out
        $(this).find('img:first').attr("src", 'http://www.adamcentric.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1-300x300.png');
    }
);
```

OR jQuery CSS class swap

```
.ofstedLogo2 {
    height: 300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url(http://www.adamcentric.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1-300x300.png); 
}
.ofstedLogo3 {
    height: 300px;
    width:300px;
    background-image:url(http://blog.modernica.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/2-300x300.png); 
}
$(".threeBox > a").hover(
    function(){ // Mouse Over
        $(this).find('div:first').toggleClass("ofstedLogo2");
        $(this).find('div:first').toggleClass("ofstedLogo3");
    },
    function(){ // Mouse Out
        $(this).find('div:first').toggleClass("ofstedLogo2");
        $(this).find('div:first').toggleClass("ofstedLogo3");
    }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rwdw5u76/

one is using an actual IMG src replace, and the other us using a css background image method instead.